# Pair up info gotten from the Places API

Tags: android, api

I am using the Places API and I have encountered that it helps retrieve information such as the place ID, ph# and the like. I am trying to pair up some data based on the getId  method to make a sort of lookup on an external data base (I'm thinking about using SQL but not sure yet) as of now, I just want to know how can I make the method to make the lookup of the information in the external database based on the placeId gotten from the API.

Somthing like, displaying in here the string that contains the result of the lookup:

```
     final CharSequence name = place.getName();
            final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
            final CharSequence phone = place.getPhoneNumber();
            final String placeId = place.getId();

            (include the retrieved data in here)

            String attribution = PlacePicker.getAttributions(data);
            if(attribution == null){
                attribution = "";
            }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated guys!.